# Firebase Realtime Database not getting updated // Data not getting added to the Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

so I'm making a chatting app, I'm facing the problem where I'm trying to add the user details to my Realtime database, and it's just not working so I can later on show them to the logged in user

this is my Register Activity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username;
    EditText email;
    EditText password;
    Button registerButton;
    TextView oldMember;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        username = findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        email = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        password = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.RegisterButton);
        oldMember = findViewById(R.id.LoginTextView);

        
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyUsers");



        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usernameText = username.getText().toString();
                String emailText = email.getText().toString();
                String passwordText = password.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usernameText) || TextUtils.isEmpty(emailText) || TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordText)){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please Fill the Required Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Register(usernameText, emailText, passwordText);
                }



            }
        });

        
        oldMember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }



    private void Register(String username, String email, String password){
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                    .getReference("MyUsers")
                                    .child(userid);


                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("id", userid);
                            hashMap.put("username", username);
                            hashMap.put("imageURL", "default");
                            

                            myRef.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainHomeActivity.class);
                                        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

[this is how my realtime database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mggc.png)

and these are my realtime database rules

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: After register, did it go to `MainHomeActivity`?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the **Tasks** objects are not successful? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine no it did not, thats when I realized that the data wasn't even getting added to the firebase realtime database.

@TarikHuber nope, none.

@AlexMamo yup I did, not much showed up actually.


thank you all for the replies, I managed to get it "fixed"
I created a new firebase project as well as recreated my android project and re-wrote everything
I enabled authentication by email and password, along side with realtime database in my firebase project before adding the `google-services.json` file to my android project, once I did all that it all worked well!

Comment: for some reason adding the json file before enabling realtime database and then enabling it made stuff not work, even though i did redownload it afterwards, kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HashMap for adding data to firebase realtime database

```
 myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .getReference("MyUsers")
                                .child(userid);


                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("id", userid);
                        hashMap.put("username", username);
                        hashMap.put("imageURL", "default");
```

Create a model class for the information

Example model class for the given information

```
public class userRegisteration(){
 Sting id;
 String username;
 String imageURL;

      //to add details it needs an empty constructor
      userRegisteration(){}

      userRegisteration(String id,String username,String imageURL){
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
      }
      public void setID(String id){this.id = id}
      public void setUsername(String username){this.username= username}
      public void setImgeURL(String imageURL){this.imageURL = imageURL}

      public String getID(){return id}
      public String getUsername(){return username}
      public String getImageURL(){return imageURL}

}
```

**Trust me** it'll work